# Send http request for api that not secure / not https in NEXTJS failed in production

Tags: javascript, api, axios, next.js

I try to send a request to a public API that not host in https but it is hot in HTTP. Its all working good In localhost but when I deploy it to vercel production build in https url. it gives an error.

```
axios.get('http://api');
```

how to overcome this?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032104/http-ajax-request-via-https-page

Comment: so this is not possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

its possible, but understand the risks, take a look at also search for "jsonp" or "cors" ajax the following answer is for jQuery but i believe if you allow in header it should work. [Jquery AJAX: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47523265/jquery-ajax-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested)

Answer (score 0):

A solution i`m using to request insecure apis through Vercel is to use a lamda function to redirect my request. You create a lambda function https on AWS or Digital Ocean and make your Next requests to that function url.